# Any alternative for a complex switch statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, switch-statement

I want to build a code for a complex switch statement. Say I give the user 3 options to choose from. Based on the option selected another 3 options are provided. Based on the selection again 3 options are provided.. and so on for 50 times. So my question is that do I create a separate component for all the options or what's a effective way of doing it?

Comment: I would probably have an array of the possible answers and each answer has its own array of Objects.

Comment: you're effectively describing nested objects. `x = { a: { a: aa, b: ab, c:ac }, b: { a: ba, b: bb, c: bc }, c: { a: ca, b: cb, c: cc } }; x['a']['b']();`

Answer (score -1):

It might be useful to define each branched switched statement as its own function. It will be a lot more readable that way.

i.e.

```
function myFunction(option) {
  switch (option.criteria1) {
    case '1':
      myFunction1(option);
      break;
    case '2':
      myFunction2(option);
      break;
    case '3':
      myFunction3(option);
      break;
    default:
      // do something
      break;
  }
}

function myFunction1(option) {
  switch (option.criteria2) {
    case 'a':
      // do something
      break;
    case 'b':
      // do something
      break;
    case 'c':
      // do something
      break;
    default:
      // do something
      break;
  }
}

// etc.
```